# can't work with XElement like with IEnumerable

Tags: c#, f#, linq-to-xml, c#-to-f#

C#

```
        var xArr = XDocument.Load(FileName)
                            .Element("dataWorkers")
                            .Elements("worker");
        int i = 0;
        foreach (XElement item in xArr)
```

F#

```
    let xArr = (((XDocument.Load fileName).Element <| XName.Get "Dict").Element <| XName.Get "dictNode")
    for x in xArr do
        ()
```

Error

```
The type 'XElement' is not a type whose values can be enumerated with this syntax, i.e. is not compatible with either seq<_>, IEnumerable<_> or IEnumerable and does not have a GetEnumerator method
```

why ? I can't find my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Element Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) returns an XElement (which is not enumerable).

The [Element**s** Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975.aspx) returns an IEnumerable<XElement>.

Answer (score 4):

In the F# code you're using `Element` which finds a *single* element rather than `Elements` which finds a *sequence* of elements.

(The C# code should be fine - there you're already using `Elements`.)